# Which epidemic involved children passing notes window to window?

Tags: disease

I remember seeing some documentary footage showing children who were required to stay home during an epidemic, passing notes and small toys back and forth with a string that was strung over a street, from window to window.  I suppose it might have been in the U.S., possibly the U.K.  Which epidemic could that have been?  I would like to show some of that footage, or read a verbal description, to my son, to help him understand the current situation.

Comment: It may not have been an epidemic, as children in the US were home-quarantined for measles, scarlet fever, and strep throat (and possibly polio) until antibiotics were developed.

Comment: @Jurp - Thanks.  I'm having trouble finding footage.  I think if I had the year that this was a phenomenon that hit the news reels, I'd have better luck.

Comment: Here's a suggestion... There is a book called The Moffats, by Eleanor Estes. It's a collection of short stories taken from Ms. Estes' own childhood. One of the stories deals with the brother of the protagonist (Janey) being quarantined for, IIRC, scarlet fever. That might help with your explanation. It's one of the stories near the end of the book, so it does have references to earlier stories. One of my favorite books when I was a kid, BTW, partly because it shows what life was like for little kids in 1910-1920 America. You could probably find it in a library (in the US, at least).

Answer (score -2):

Around 1950 there was a polio epidemic in many countries. Children were particularly affected and so were isolated. Video on Youtube "History of Polio".

Comment: A source providing evidence of what the OP is asking is needed, so this doesn't really answer the question.